# Test for proper exception with Pytest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pytest

I want to test if a Django Rest Framework returns the proper exception when required, but the test always fails when the exception is raised, instead of succeeding when the exception is the right one:

This is my view:

```
@api_view(http_method_names=['GET'])
def get_fibonacci(request: Request) -> Response:
    """
    Calculates the fibonacci value for number sent as query_param 'n'
    """

    try:
        n = int(request.query_params['n'])
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("The value of 'n' must be an integer.")

    fibonacci_of_n = fibonacci_dynamic_v2(n)

    return Response(fibonacci_of_n)
```

And this is my test:

```
def test_n_is_a_string_returns_proper_exception(client) -> None:
    test_url = f"{fibonacci_url}?n=str"
    response = client.get(test_url)
    assert response.status_code == 404
```

And this is the result of the test:

```
=============================== short test summary info =======================================
FAILED tests/test_api.py::test_n_is_a_string_returns_proper_exception - ValueError: The value of 'n' must be an integer.

Results (1.08s):
      23 passed
       1 failed
         - api/coronavstech/fibonacci_methods/tests/test_api.py:20 test_n_is_a_string_returns_proper_exception
```

I don't know how to instruct Pytest to succeed the test when the exception is the right one, instead of failing it because there was an exception, which is the result expected from the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For catching the exception, you can use [`pytest.raises()`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions) like follows:

```
def test_n_is_a_string_returns_proper_exception(client) -> None:
    test_url = f"{fibonacci_url}?n=str"
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        response = client.get(test_url)
```

You can even check the exception message:

```
def test_n_is_a_string_returns_proper_exception(client) -> None:
    test_url = f"{fibonacci_url}?n=str"
    with pytest.raises(ValueError, match="^The value of 'n' must be an integer\.$"):
        response = client.get(test_url)
```

But the `ValueError` being thrown inside your view is probably not what you wanted, as it will be shown as a generic 500 error.